Game identification in which the human protagonist gets infected by an alien green virus, eventually giving Hulk-like powers
I am starting a video-game remembrance series with my father. After recalling Inca, Discworld and still looking for other that I might ask for here, we have looked a lot for this one to no avail. Everything described here is really fuzzy, do not take it as granted.
Setting
You are (possibly) a human, infected with a (surely) green little organism looking like a mantis. I guess it could be an alien bacteria. You escape somehow from where you were and start roaming the street (maybe) to look for a cure. You sometimes get superpowers making you green, but we never got to Hulk-mode that I think existed. Other humans seem to have been infected too, albeit they are red and zombie-like. Think Prototype game's hero. Maybe there are some cops, and you can shoot bullets and pickup guns. Most likely you can crouch too, and hide behind trash cans. You have some really hard jumps to make to avoid street level. Urban landscape, at least for the starting levels.
Platform and date
2D platformer, non-scrolling I think, more panel-based levels. Awful junky animations (hence the failed jumps). Definitely PC, say 1990's. CD-ROM version running on I would say Windows 95.
At least in the French edition, the name as we recall sounds and/or looks like "Akhlys" (yes, like the black metal band).
